# Run A Java Program That Calls On An External Jar

Tags: java, windows, command-line, command, fileutils

I'm trying to run a Java program that calls on the C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\commons-io-2.4 folder. It compiled fine with this code `javac -cp "C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\commons-io-2.4\*" Login.java` but when I tried to run it with this code 
   `java -cp C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\commons-io-2.4\* Login` it gave me this`error: Could not find or load main class Login.class` How do I fix this?
P.S. The program calls on the FileUtils.

Comment: Is the class in a package?

Comment: In the actual code I didn't state package I just said import org.apache.commons.io.fileutils

Comment: I mean what package is `Login` in?

Comment: It's just in c:users/Brandon/desktop/javacode

Comment: Does the first line of `Login.java` say `package *.*.*;`

Comment: No It doesn't it's the normal public class login then the void main string args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the current location as part of classpath.

```
java -cp .;C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\commons-io-2.4\* Login
```

symbol .(dot) is the current path, separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `java -cp C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\commons-io-2.4\*;. Login`
You have to add the current directory to the class path
If that doesn't work try `java -cp C:\Users\Brandon\Downloads\commons-io-2.4\* -cp . Login`

Comment: These didn't work but thanks for the input and being patient for a beginner like me. I'm only 15 so I'm just getting started

Comment: I typed : instead of ;. Dang it. And i'm 13. If been coding since 10.